# Package for interacting with the AR.Drone by Todd Gayley?

Tags: packages

Anyone in possesion of the package develop by Todd Gayley to interact with the AR.Drone? Haven't been able to find it anywhere... Referring to this video:

http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=104/?fp=left&video=1371&sortBy=title

Comment: You might want to ping @ToddGayley :-)

Comment: I, too, would be interested; although it has been many years, it still seems to me to be the only real package that allows you to do many things directly from Mathematica. I do not understand why it is not found, either for sale or free, and I have not been able to contact the author. Robotics is too important not to do it with Mathematica! Does anybody know something?